# Matlab coordinate system different from our usual one

Tags: matlab, coordinate-systems

I notice that in Matlab, the coordinates system is a little different but I cannot be sure if my observations are correct. I notice that the X and Y axes are in opposite when I am trying to do some simple image processing:

The vertical axis in Matlab is its X-axis while the horizontal one is its Y-axis. I noticed this when I was trying to crop an image with `Im(XX:XX, YY:YY)` and it turns out that the `YY:YY` part actually represents the horizontal length instead of vertical.

So is it true that the coorindates in Matlab switch our usual X-axis to its Y-axis and our usual Y-axis to its X-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pay attention to the difference between **coordinate system** and **matrix indexing**. When you access elements in a matrix (like in `Im( a:b, c:d )`) you have to provide indices of **rows** and then **columns**: `Im( from_row : to_row, from_col : to_col )`.
Now it may be a bit confusing since rows are in the Y direction and columns are in the X direction.

Comment: So in Matlab, a point of `(X=5, Y=10)` is still `(X=5, Y=10)`. There is no change in the coordinates system. It is just the way when defining the matrix indexes that it reads different, did I understand correctly?

Comment: @Carven When you plot something, you reference a point using its Cartesian coordinate (x,y). However, when you access a matrix entry, you access it using its (row,column) values.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab is in something called [Row-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order).

You say the row first and then the column, as is standard in mathematics.

I personally remember this from the formula of a the dot product which is `row-dot-column`.

[image: http://www.terramath.com/tutorials/basics/col_row_major.jpg]

Comment: Ohh..so there is actually no difference in Matlab's coordinate. So when I talk about a point of `(X=5, Y=10)` in Matlab, I wouldn't have to say `(X=10, Y=5)`, right? I just define it as the usual standard coordinate. The only time it has this row-major order thing is when I define the pixels to crop. Is this right?

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that, while you **index** arrays in row-major order, MATLAB actually **stores** data in column major order.

Comment: @wakjah certainly, but Matlab has a JIT so what it does is never clear. I once had a matrix and transposed it and noticed identical runtime, which hints to me that it choose the best way to store the data.